# 80's-90's TV show or movie about life clocks

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

It's from the late 80's early 90's I saw it on PBS I think. Everyone had a life clock installed at birth.

Everything bought and sold was with time increments. No one went to prison, time was just subtracted. When you ran out you died. I remember an addict begging for time before they died.

I have been looking for this one for years.

Comment: Much later (2011), but this sounds similar to [In Time](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/?ref_=m_nm_knf_i3).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be the 1987 short ["The Price of Life"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366919/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) which I found referenced on the Wikipedia page for ["In Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Time) (2011).

I have never heard of this, so I'm just going to quote [the Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Price_of_Life_(1987_film)):

> The basic premise of the film is that a time account is physically linked to every infant at birth, with death automatic when the balance drops to zero. An elite upper-class is portrayed as living hundreds of years or more. The protagonist is given a certain amount of time as an infant, and as a young boy adds days and years to his time account by buying valuables from people and selling them to visiting tourists from the rich enclave. After his sister dies after gambling away her time, the protagonist (now a young man) sets out on a journey to the enclave of "the Old Ones" in order to save the life of his mother, who is (literally) running out of time. He gets there and meets a beautiful older woman who co-opts him into the immortal lifestyle.

Comment: @Valorum Nice find, thank you!

Comment: It's been on Youtube since 2014 so I assume the rights-holders are broadly happy that it's there.

Comment: Fair warning.  That opening scene with the baby is deeply disturbing.

Comment: @KyleJones - And appallingly acted. Also the special effects are abysmal.

Comment: @Valorum In this case, thankfully.  I don't think I want to see that with good acting and effects.

Comment: That is the one :) thank you so much. You folks are great!! I've got one more I will ask in a few.

Comment: Wonder if there is a similar situation with this movie and in time as there was with the island and clonus